# In Strategy Pattern, can't we make each strategy as a function but not as a class?

Tags: design-patterns

In the usual Strategy Pattern, we make each strategy as a class.  Can't we make it a function, and just assign the reference to the function when we instantiate an object, and let the object call that function?

Comment: Have fun with Java in that case :)

Comment: why?  Java can't support reference to function?

Comment: +1 for thinking critically about Design Patterns. I'd say many design patterns stem from the root of the incapability of the language. So in many instances, design patterns are not bibles :)

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The strategy pattern is for object-oriented languages that do not support first-class functions. It simulates a function pointer with an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest cases, you can replace Strategy patterns with a function pointer. However, consider this case

```
class HourlyPayStrategy implements PayStrategy
{
    public int calculate()
    {
        int x = doComplexOperation1();
        int y = doComplexOperation2();

        return x + y;
    }

    private int doComplexOperation1()
    {
        // ...
    }

    private int doComplexOperation2()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If we just gave a simple function pointer, things start getting really hairy because you can no longer refactor that thing (well, at least not in an well encapsulated way).

Comment: I disagree with this. Whether you reference HourlyPayStrategy or HourlyPayStrategy.calculate makes no difference in terms refactoring or encapsulation.

Comment: @DavidArno by your notation I believe your acquainted to C#, which does a nice job performing _eta expansion_. That notation is not at all easy to achieve in many languages: JavaScript, Ruby, Python, Java, OCaml even (speaking from several year old memory), C++ (questions: how does C++11 gibe with this nowadays?).

Comment: In many languages when one expects a _function_ as parameter it is quite different from expecting a _method_, where the compiler / runtime would need to carry around with the associated object. So then yes, for C# your argument has legs.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the language. In C#, you could make it a delegate. In Java, it would rather be a anonymous class. In C++, you could really make it a function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, although by using objects you can take advantage of inheritance in ways that you couldn't with just functions.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can use delegates with the strategy pattern. Take a look at this 
[blog post](http://brucezhang.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/strategy-pattern-and-delegate/) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

What happens below the hood in most C++ implementations is almost what you suggest. The compiler usually resolves a call Strategy.virtualMethod() like this (in pseudo code):

```
  (Strategy.pVtable[indexOfVirtualMethod])()
```

So if your only concern is the one more dereferencing of a pointer (pVtable) you should really profile first if you cannot identify more serious hotspots.

My feeling is that your code will be much harder to understand and maintain when you use a function pointer instead of a strategy object.